# Is there a way to produce a gather_at or gather_if function similar to mutate_at or mutate_if

Tags: r, dplyr

I think the title is rather straight forward.
But just to provide some data and example:

```
test <- tibble(
ID1 = letters,
ID2 = LETTERS,
A1 = runif(26),
B1 = runif(26),
A2 = runif(26),
B2 = runif(26)
)
```

Is there a way to gather on only e.g., numerical columns with a `simple` command such that:

```
test %>% gather_if(is.numeric, 'key', 'value')
```

? Which would give the same output as the following:

```
> test %>% gather('key', 'value', -ID1, -ID2)
# A tibble: 104 x 4
   ID1   ID2   key    value
   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 a     A     A1    0.558 
 2 b     B     A1    0.0614
 3 c     C     A1    0.999 
 4 d     D     A1    0.854 
 5 e     E     A1    0.463 
 6 f     F     A1    0.875 
 7 g     G     A1    0.796 
 8 h     H     A1    0.484 
 9 i     I     A1    0.336 
10 j     J     A1    0.191 
# ... with 94 more rows
```

Looking at the gather function:

```
> gather
function (data, key = "key", value = "value", ..., na.rm = FALSE, 
    convert = FALSE, factor_key = FALSE) 
{
    UseMethod("gather")
}
<bytecode: 0x000000001b71ff18>
<environment: namespace:tidyr>
```

It does not seem that straight forward to modify it (at least not for me who is a semi-novel R user).

**Edit:**

My vocabulary choice in dplyr might not be exactly accurate. But I think the MWE explains fairly well what type of function I'm going for.

**Edit2:**

Using the answer by bschneidr, an ad-hoc version of this could be done in the following way.

```
gather_if <- function(data, fun, key, value, ..., na.rm = FALSE, convert = 
FALSE, factor_key = FALSE){
    data %>%
        gather(!!key, !!value, select_if(., fun) %>% colnames(), ...,
               na.rm = FALSE, convert = FALSE, factor_key = FALSE)
}
```

Which gives:

```
> test %>% gather_if(is.numeric, 'key', 'value')
# A tibble: 104 x 4
   ID1   ID2   key    value
   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 a     A     A1    0.558 
 2 b     B     A1    0.0614
 3 c     C     A1    0.999 
 4 d     D     A1    0.854 
 5 e     E     A1    0.463 
 6 f     F     A1    0.875 
 7 g     G     A1    0.796 
 8 h     H     A1    0.484 
 9 i     I     A1    0.336 
10 j     J     A1    0.191 
# ... with 94 more rows
```

Comment: Is the problem that you need it to be done programmatically without specifying `ID1`and `ID2`?

Comment: @Sotos Yes, that is exactly what I'm going for! :) I just want to exclude all categorical columns in the gather but keep them as separate columns. If that makes sense? I guess I could first identify the categorical columns and store them as symbols or some rlang tidy_eval. But it would seem, to me, that this type of function that I'm suggesting could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a `gather_if` function is in the works for tidyr (see [this pull request](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/pull/489) on tidyr's Github repo).

For the moment, I think the easiest method is to use dplyr's `select_if` function inside the call to `gather`.

```
test %>% 
    gather('key', 'value',
           colnames(select_if(., is.numeric)))
```

Comment: Oh, that is great! Then I guess this thread is semi pointless. Is there a way to evaluate is.numeric as any general function using e.g., rlang? That way making an ad-hoc function in the meantime would be fairly simple.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you've figured that out and added that to the question, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks to you! :) Making a last edit now and it should be working properly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to `negate()` the numeric condition and extract the names. It does look a bit cumbersome but here it is,

```
library(tidyverse)

gather(test, key, value, -c(test %>% select_if(negate(is.numeric)) %>% names()))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 104 x 4
>    ID1   ID2   key    value
>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
>  1 a     A     A1    0.624 
>  2 b     B     A1    0.0740
>  3 c     C     A1    0.790 
>  4 d     D     A1    0.312 
>  5 e     E     A1    0.323 
>  6 f     F     A1    0.826 
>  7 g     G     A1    0.0533
>  8 h     H     A1    0.0828
>  9 i     I     A1    0.979 
> 10 j     J     A1    0.453 
> # ... with 94 more rows
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If think you want this:

```
gather_if <- function(data, FUN, key = "key", value = "value", na.rm = FALSE, convert = FALSE, factor_key = FALSE) {
    data %>% {gather(., key = key, value = value , names(.)[sapply(., FUN = FUN)], na.rm = na.rm, convert = convert, factor_key = factor_key )}
}
```

call your new cool function:

```
test %>% gather_if(is.numeric, 'key', 'value')
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 104 x 4
#   ID1   ID2   key   value
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a     A     A1    0.693
# 2 b     B     A1    0.356
# 3 c     C     A1    0.650
# 4 d     D     A1    0.358
# 5 e     E     A1    0.650
# 6 f     F     A1    0.461
# 7 g     G     A1    0.222
# 8 h     H     A1    0.993
# 9 i     I     A1    0.679
#10 j     J     A1    0.331
# ... with 94 more rows
```